# How to calculate the center position of a circle tangent to two line segments?

Tags: geometry

How to calculate the center position of a circle tangent to two line segments?

[image]

Known:
The position of **B** is (4,0,0), **A** is (0,0,0), **C** is (-3,3,0)
The included angle of **BAC** is 135 degrees, and **AD** is the angle bisector.
**DE**, **DF** is the radius of the circle, perpendicular to **AC** and **AB**, and the length is 3.

Now I want to know the position of point **D**.

The method I can think of is to use the Law of Sines to find the length of **AD**, and then use it as the radius to draw a circle. something like:

```
x = cos(θ) * radius
y = sin(θ) * radius
```

[image]

But this method is not easy to deal with 3D problems. I think there should be a better way.

UPDATE1:
**D** is coplanar with **ABC**.

Comment: If $D$ is coplanar with $ABC$ then you have the solution. If it's not, then there are infinitely many circles in 3D which are tangent to those two lines.

Comment: D is coplanar with ABC.

Comment: Then what is the difficulty? You have point $A$ plus the direction and length of $AD$.

Comment: how to do that? (0,0,0) + (length of AD)?

Comment: You know $\,DF=3\,$, $AF = DF / \tan \frac{135^\circ}{2}$ then $\,D\,$ is $\,(0,0,0)+(AF,DF,0)\,$.

Comment: I just found a new way:
1. Treat AB and AC as vectors and "normalize" them.
2. Average the two "normalized" vectors to get the direction of the angle bisector.
3. Normalize this "direction" and multiply it by the length of AD to get the position of D!

Comment: You just run parallel to AB or AC at distance 3.